# No branch matches prefix

Tags: git, git-flow

When I run

```
git flow feature finish -S branchname
```

I get the following message

> No branch matches prefix 'branchname'

However, when I run

```
git branch -a
```

`branchname` is listed in the list of branches. What might be the issue?

Comment: Which version of `git flow` are you using? And is it the AVH edition?

Comment: Which type (feature, release, hotfix or support) of branch is it? Can you post the `[gitflow *]` sections of `.git/config`?

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was find the right name of the branch. 
For list all  features that you have, use:

```
git flow feature
```

Answer (score 1):

try updating your local to whats in your origin:

`$ git fetch -p origin`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of missing local branch `feature/FEATURE_NAME`:

```
git checkout feature/FEATURE_NAME
```